# how i can retrieve all rows depend on one emp_id in ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[image]

I want to pass Emp_id and want to retrieve all other employees which are replaces on previous employees.
for example, if EMP_ID =1 leave then new EMP_ID REPLACEMENT is 2 same as EMP_ID = 2 if this leave then REPLACEMENT ID 3. If last EMP_ID = 4 then how i can retrive all previous emp_id's base on last.
I want to do in oracle sql query

Comment: I believe what you're after is known as a Hierarchical Query addressed using recursive WITH Clauses.  You can find more info for your version of Oracle here https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2

Comment: Not working... Share some more details plz

Comment: Sorry to say but the explanation is confusing. Could you add your expected result as well with one or two test scenarios.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. What are your result expectation? Could you please update question with desired output? For example "I pass 1 and get 4" in result and so on

Answer (score 0):

> If last `EMP_ID = 4` then how I can retreive all previous `emp_id`'s based on last.

Use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT emp_id
FROM   table_name
START WITH rep_emp_id = 4
CONNECT BY rep_emp_id = PRIOR emp_id;
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( emp_id, emp_name, rep_emp_id ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Kamran', 2    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Aftab',  3    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Rashid', 4    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Saqib',  NULL FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> | EMP_ID |
> | -----: |
> |      3 |
> |      2 |
> |      1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f1cff62508dd06f2bae823b6dce758d)*

Comment: Thanks for reply... But this is not working fine. My Question was if an employee hired in a company his id is 321 and when next employee hired then its id will be new 676 but replacement id will be 321.so, i  get last employee 676 then it should also get 321 employee. but if a new employee hired but not against this employees then no need to retrive.

Comment: @kamranijaz Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64041085/edit) your question with a [MRE] including: DDL statements for your tables; DML statements for sample data that represents the issue (as text, not images that we can't copy/paste from); a detailed description of the problem; and your expected output. I have answered the question you asked originally; if your problem is something that is not covered in your original question then how can we answer it?

Comment: i.e. show a fully worked small example of what your source data is and what you expect the result to look like.

Comment: Perhaps a small tweak to the hierarchical query to add the other employee id makes it clearer? `SELECT emp_id, rep_emp_id as "Replaced By" FROM table_name START WITH rep_emp_id = 4 CONNECT BY rep_emp_id = PRIOR emp_id;`